# If $A \subseteq B$ and if $A$ dedekind-infinite, then $B$ dedekind-infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question about the above theorem. I try to prove it on my own.

First we have the premises, i.e. $A‘ \subset A$ and $f: A \to A‘$ bijective, as well as $ A \subseteq B$.

Then we define a new function $g: f \cup id^{B-A}$, so that $g(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in A$ and $g(x) = x$ for $x \in B-A$. Now, because of $A‘ \subset A$ we get $rng(g) = A‘ \cup (B-A) \subset B$.

But to prove B dedekind-infinite I also need to show that $h: B \to rng(g)$ is bijective. But how can that be done? I neither see the idea nor the formalization.

Comment: You just have to show that $g$ is injective.*

Comment: Where did $h$ come from? You already built $g$ specifically to fill this role, so why suddenly are you abandoning it and looking for a different function? You know the definition of $g$. It is built from two non-overlapping injective functions. Just use that definition to show that it must be injective.

Comment: Hmm, why do I have to show that g is injective? I thought I need to show that B -> rng(g) is an bijective function. What has g to do wirh it?